# Edit specific row in an Access 2013 table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have `Table1` with `CustomerID` and `Category` as a primary key, and a form I'm using to edit this table. There are several `FieldComboBoxes` in the form containing other information, and `CategoryComboBox` which updates the table after I select an option.

What I'm trying to do is find if the primary key exists in the table, and if it does, find and edit that row. I'm using VBA in the On Change event of CategoryComboBox:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

If Not IsNull(DLookup("CustomerID", "Table1", "CustomerID = " & [CustomerID] AND _
"Category = '" & CategoryComboBox.Value & "'")) Then
        rec.Edit
        rec!CustomerID = CustomerID
        rec!Category = CategoryComboBox.Value

        rec!Field1 = Field1ComboBox.Value
        rec!Field2 = Field2ComboBox.Value
        ...

        rec.Update
End If
```

If a row with the same primary key as the current record in the form exists in the table, I expect it to update the row, but what happens is that it updates the second row in the table regardless of PrimaryKey. I also tried adding `If Category = CategoryComboBox.Value` before the AddNew command but it has no effect.

In short, how can I get Access to select and edit a specific row - in my case, the row with the correct primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code says "if a record exists in Table1 for this customer and category, then add a new record to table one for this customer and category" If, as you describe, you were editing the existing row rather than adding a new one, then your edit would be a no-op because you are setting Customer and Category to match what were already your criteria--so I assume something is missing from your example and that's shown below with [other_field] and 'new value'.

First off, for an operation like you describe it is much faster to use SQL directly rather than create a recordset, objectify the record, and update through VBA.  EG:

```
currentdb.execute "UPDATE Table1 set [other_field] = 'new value' where CustemerID = " & CustemerID & " AND Category = '" CategoryComboBox.Value & "';"
```

But if you did have something complicated and needed a VBA hook to the record then first choice would be to restrict recordset:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordSet "select * from Table1 where customerID = " & CustomerID & " AND CategoryComboBox.Value = '" & CategoryComboBox.Value & "';"
if rec.RecordCount > 0 then
  rec.movefirst
  rec.edit
  rec.[other field] = 'new value'
  rec.update
  rec.close
end if
```

Again, let as much be done by sql as possible.

If you really need everything in recordset for other reasons then

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordSet "Table1"
if rec.RecordCount > 0 then
  rec.findfirst("customerID = " & CustomerID & " AND CategoryComboBox.Value = '" & CategoryComboBox.Value & "'")
  if not rec.nomatch then
    rec.edit
    rec.[other field] = 'new value'
    rec.update
    rec.close
  end if 
end if
```

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention there are other fields in the table! I edited my question.

Comment: Your answer worked. I used SQL in my query and it now updates the exact row. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? I'm confused how it will know which record to update based on the customerID, since I think there could be multiple, but I think this will get you closer.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

If IsNull(DLookup("CustomerID", "Table1", "CustomerID = " & Me![CustomerID] AND _
"Category = '" & Me!CategoryComboBox.Value & "'")) Then
    rec.AddNew
    rec!CustomerID = CustomerID
    rec!Category = CategoryComboBox.Value
    rec.Update
ELSE:
    sql = "UPDATE Table1 SET Category = " & Me!CategoryComboBox.Value & " WHERE CustomerID = " & Me![CustomerID]
    DoCmd.RunSql sql
End If

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the Category to the sql query is needed to pinpoint the row, but what sense is there updating it if it already has the correct category value? That's what's confusing me.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to mention there are other fields in the table! I edited my question.

Comment: Using SQL instead of RecordSet editing solved my issue, thanks!